# How to remove content on the jQuery UI dialog via ulr load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

i already got it to work but the problem is when i remove the content the main page content is removed as well because have the same class name. how can i control only the modal content and remove certain classes without removing them from the parent page.

```
        var $modalDialog = $('<div/>', { 
      'class': 'exampleModal', 
      'id': 'exampleModal1'
    })



    .appendTo('body')
    .dialog({

       resizable: true,
       title:'Approval',
       autoOpen: false,
       width:'auto',
       height:'auto',
       show: 'fold',
       position:  { my: "right top", at: "top" },
       modal: true,
  close: function(event, ui) {
      location.reload();
 }
    }).css("overflow", "auto"); 


    $(function () {
        $('a.exampleLink').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // TODO: Undo comments, below
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $modalDialog.load(url, function(){
        $( ".ewMenu" ).hide(); $( ".ewHeaderRow" ).hide();     $('h4').hide();          


 $( "#btnCancel" ).hide(); $( ".ewToolbar" ).hide();    $( ".ewFooterRow" ).hide();
            });

            $modalDialog.dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (example for btnCancel):

```
$modalDialog.find("#btnCancel").hide();
```

Comment: where should i place that exactly i placed it at the end did not work also after the .dialog but nothing. it only works in  $modalDialog.load(url, function but then it affects the parent page as well

Comment: If you want to remove that in modal load function, you need to do this:
$modalDialog.find( ".ewMenu" ).hide(); 
$modalDialog.find( ".ewHeaderRow" ).hide();
$modalDialog.find('h4').hide();          
$modalDialog.find( "#btnCancel" ).hide(); 
$modalDialog.find( ".ewToolbar" ).hide();
$modalDialog.find( ".ewFooterRow" ).hide();

instead of your calling hide function on every classes